# Combine two table in one Entities Framework entity with DefiningQuery

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

I am having difficulties combining two entities into one where one is a DefiningQuery of readonly data.

I have a Person entity and a Company entity the Person entity is related to the Company entity throught the Company.CompanyID to the Person.CompanyID as one-to-many.  The data for the Company comes from a different database so its represented as a DefiningQuery in my SSDL with a key.  I want to make the fields in Company part of the Person entity by combining the entities.

> Error 3024: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line 445:Must
>   specify mapping for all key properties
>   (Person.PersonID) of the EntitySet
>   Person.

I assume the issue is that the Company entity does not have a PersonID but I don't want to make a Company a DefiningQuery with both PersonID and CompanyID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Person` and `Company` in one-to-many relation and because of that you cannot map `Person` and `Company` fields into same entity. This type of mapping is called entity splitting and it requires one-to-one relation between tables which can be in EF defined only on shared primary key (because EF doesn't support unique constraints).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I had discovered that recently and made the Company DefininingQuery flat and added the PersonID to the Company entity so it looks like a 1:1 relationship. Now when I add a person I get the following error:  `System.Data.UpdateException : Unable to update the EntitySet 'CompanyView' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.`

Comment: Sure once you use DefiningQuery your entity is read only unless you create and map stored procedures for insert, update and delete.

Comment: I want it to be readonly because I don't want to update the company.  What I believe now is its not supported to combine an updateable table with DefingingQuery that is readonly into a single entity.